# Change entries in Pandas Dataframe if str exists in entry

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe of IDs and Dates, which for some reason when I implement `pd.read_excel` adds an extra significant figure to the end of IDs and DATEs that don't have a decimal point. Below is what my dataframe looks like:

```
>>> df

       ID           DATE
0   104555.0      20101203.0
1   101034.0      20140306.0
2   101284.01     20160723.0
```

And here's what the dataframe should look like (what comes out of the Excel Worksheet):

```
       ID           DATE
0   104555        20101203
1   101034        20140306
2   101284.01     20160723
```

The third entry should have '.01' at the end of its ID. There are several other cases that follow this with other examples like '.02', '.03', etc.

How do I iterate over the entries and change them if '.0' exists?

```
for index, row, in df.itterows():
   if df[df['ID'].str.contains(".0")]:
       .....
```

Or, better yet, are there any options with `pd.read_excel` that keeps values intact?

Comment: I'm not sure why your date column is converted to a float.  Try sorting the values and look for outliers.  Perhaps you have something like 2014.12 which then causes the whole column to be cast as floats.

Comment: In the first case, `pandas` sees the third ID cell as a float and so chooses to make everything a float since all other values are numeric-like. As for the date, do you have any blank cells? pandas would make these `NaN`, which forces an upcasting to float. You could try to specify `dtype={'DATE', 'Int64', 'ID': 'str'}` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
df = pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xlsx', dtype={'ID':str})
```

and then:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.extract('(.*)\.0+$').fillna(df['ID'])
```

Output:

```
         ID        DATE
0    104555  20101203.0
1    101034  20140306.0
2  104555.0  20160723.0
```